# Spring MVC - Using @PathVariable doesn't find the JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, annotations

I am using the **@PathVariable** annotation to provide an ID to my controller. When I do this, it finds the mapping and runs the code within the controller method, but when it comes to load the JSP it cannot find it and I get the error below.

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing
>   /Timesheets/viewtimesheet/WEB-INF/pages/viewtimesheet.jsp. Reason:
>
> Not Found

In the log I get the following error:

> SEVERE: PWC6117: File "C:\dev\Projects\DominoTimesheets\WebContent\viewtimesheet\WEB-INF\pages\viewtimesheets.jsp" not found

If I take out the **@PathVariable** then it runs fine and loads the page as expected (but I need to have the `timesheetId` to runs against the database). The path above has `viewtimesheet` before the WEB-INF which is causing the issues. It seems that it does not like the mapping of `/viewtimesheet/{timesheetID}` Can someone shed any light on this?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/viewtimesheet/{timesheetID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)   
public String viewTimesheet(@PathVariable int timesheetID, ModelMap model, 
   final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpSession session) {      

   Timesheets timesheetResult = timesheetsService.getTimesheet(timesheetID);

   model.addAttribute("mondayDate", timesheetResult.getDate_WC());      
   model.addAttribute("viewTimesheetModel", timesheetResult);

   return "viewtimesheets";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. The **InternalResourceViewResolver** bean in the **dispatcher-servlet**  required a slash before the prefix value.

```
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
```

This loaded the page as expected without the extra **viewtimesheet** in the url:

> SEVERE: PWC6117: File
>   "C:\dev\Projects\DominoTimesheets\WebContent\viewtimesheet\WEB-INF\pages\viewtimesheets.jsp"
>   not found